# SQL data query request

Tags: mysql

I'd appreciate your help with an SQL problem.

I have some student quiz score data in an SQL table and I wish to write a query to extract the information that I want. Candidates can attempt the tests as many times as they wish. Ideally, for each candidate, I wish to find out their highest percentage score on each of the tests. And I wish to get an average percentage of their highest percentage score on each test. Many of the candidates will not have done all of the tests. For example, candidate 1's highest scores on tests 1, 2 and 3 are 50%, 100% and 0%, leaving an overall average of 50%.

The table is named resultsets. The relevant column titles names are: Candidate (this is the student ID number), QuizName (the title of each quiz), and PercentageScore. It looks like this:

```
Candidate | QuizName | PercentageScore 
---------------------------------------
1         | Test1    | 25              
1         | Test1    | 50              
1         | Test2    | 100             
1         | Test3    | 0               
2         | Test1    | 50              
2         | Test1    | 100              
3         | Test3    | 75
```

I'm hoping to get a table that looks something like this:

```
Candidate | Test1 | Test 2 | Test 3 | AveragePercentageScore 
---------------------------------------
1         | 50    | 100    |  0     | 50                 
2         | 50    | 100    |  0     | 50             
3         | 0     | 0      |  75    | 25
```

(Thanks Jain) I'd like to know the SQL command that I should enter.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to know?

Comment: You have explained what you want - now you need to show what you have tried so far & say why it is not getting the results you want. Showing your tables & example data would help us to help you.

Comment: Thanks for you comment PaulF. I'm a real beginner at this, and I've just been fumbling around. I don't think my failed attempts would be a very helpful guide.

Comment: please execute the following and add/edit the results

Comment: `show create table yourtablename;`

Comment: Showing what you have tried demonstrates your efforts in solving your own problem. Here, on SO we like to assist in resolving issues, but do not like to completely solve them instead of the OP. So, show your yables, show some sample data, provide sample expected output, privide any attempts to solve the above question along with any error messages or unexpected behaviour you encountered.

Comment: `select * from yourtablename limit 20`

Comment: Thank you for your comment Shadow. I've added a table of sample data, and hoped for output. As a rank beginner, I've just been learning how to make queries.

Comment: Typically, issues of data display are best handled in a presentation layer/application level code, if that's available. Otherwise see PIVOT TABLE QUERIES

Comment: Also, you have no PRIMARY KEY, which could prove problematic further down the road - and candidate 2 scored 100 on test 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from being a beginner, it would be good to get a handle on basic table / database structures, relationships, use of primary / foreign keys and especially data normalization.

As for learning queries, I have seen other people utilize [SQL Zoo](http://sqlzoo.net/) as it has sample data and covers samples of how to look for certain things that require different query, joins, left-joins, aggregates etc.

All that said, sometimes it makes things easier if you can understand queries based on YOUR data, not some generic sample database that you have no context on its application to your data.

With all that said, I will help you get started.  You need aggregates (min, max, avg, count) that are typically applicable based on a "GROUP BY" column(s).  In this first case, you want to find "for each candidate" (the group by), and each "QUIZ" for that CANDIDATE (also part of group by), you want the highest test.

```
SELECT
      Q.candidate,
      Q.quizname,
      MAX( Q.PercentageScore ) as HighestScore
   from
      YourQuizTable Q
   group by
      Q.candidate,
      Q.quizname
```

Will result in the following.

```
Candidate   QuizName    HighestScore
1           Test1       50
1           Test2       100
1           Test3       0    (a legit score on file)
2           Test1       100
3           Test3       75
```

From that, you could create a pivot.  Now, different sql engines have different pivot syntax, but to better see on these specific quizes posted, I will be doing a hard-coded pivot.  Since the pivot is derived (uses the first query as the basis), the first query IS the basis of the pivot.

```
SELECT
      smry.Candidate,
      if( smry.quizname = 'Test1', smry.HighestScore, 0 ) as HiTest1,
      if( smry.quizname = 'Test2', smry.HighestScore, 0 ) as HiTest2,
      if( smry.quizname = 'Test3', smry.HighestScore, 0 ) as HiTest3,
      AVG( smry.HighestScore ) as AvgTest
   from
      ( SELECT
              Q.candidate,
              Q.quizname,
              MAX( Q.PercentageScore ) as HighestScore
           from
              YourQuizTable Q
           group by
              Q.candidate,
              Q.quizname ) smry
   group by
      smry.Candidate
```

The "IF()" is applied as each row is attempted, and each row will only ever have an instance of 1 quizname, it would only be either "Test1", "Test2" or "Test3".  IF it IS that proper test, then grab the highest score as the basis to show in that column result.  The last column is a simple average.

The final group by is now keeping them per candidate, but this time WITHOUT the group of the quiz as the inner query had.

Comment: Thank you DRapp for your tremendous help. The first set of code certainly works. Then, I assume I have to work out how to save the resulting table and use it as the input for the second set of code. The SQL Zoo link was also useful.